# MySQL tables for BasicAuth in Glassfish

Tags: mysql, rest, glassfish, basic-authentication

I'm deploying RESTful Web Services in NetBeans 7.3, using Jersey.
I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2, and data from a MySQL Database.
Now I want to configure **Basic-Authentication**.

I followed some tutorials first, with just 3 tables in the Database, like in this:
http://jugojava.blogspot.pt/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html

and all went fine. But now, I want to apply that in my DB. 
The tables must follow certain rules, right? I'm trying to create 2 new tables: **groups**, and **login_groups** (just like in the tutorial, but my table that is named 'users' in the tutorial, is my table named '**login**', that already exists).
But I can't create a **Foreign Key** between the tables login_groups, and login.
I allready create one between login_groups and groups, and I had no problem.

Here are my code tables:

Table **login**:

```
  CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `privileges` enum('system','installer','administrator') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `secret_id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `User_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `isLogged` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `Language` enum('Portuguese','English') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `secret_id_UNIQUE` (`secret_id`),
  KEY `fk_Login_User1` (`User_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Login_User1` FOREIGN KEY (`User_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Table **groups**:

```
 CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lul`.`groups` (
`group_id` MEDIUMINT(8) NOT NULL ,
`group_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`group_desc` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

Table **login_groups**:

```
  CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lul`.`login_groups` (
  `login_id` MEDIUMINT(8) NOT NULL ,
  `group_id` MEDIUMINT(8) NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`login_id`, `group_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_login` (`login_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_groups` (`group_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_login`
  FOREIGN KEY (`login_id` ) REFERENCES `lul`.`login` (`id` )
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_groups`
  FOREIGN KEY (`group_id` ) REFERENCES `lul`.`groups` (`group_id` )
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_bin
```

And the error that is given in MySQL when I'm trying to create the **Foreign Key** between the tables login_groups and login is:

**Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: 
Can't create table 'lul.login_groups' (errno: 150)**

Note that I've tried to create the Foreign Keys separately, and I could create the second one.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
Or do you know another way to use tables for Basic-Authentication?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So I ran your SQL through my copy of MySQL, and the only error I got was in the `CREATE TABLE  login` script; it didn't like the reference to table `user` in

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_Login_User1` FOREIGN KEY (`User_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

which I presume you've already defined elsewhere?

No problem at all with table `login_groups`.  Are you trying to alter existing tables with data, where that data violates any of the desired constraints [id being referenced in another table isn't defined in that table]?

Comment: Thanks Richard, but I already solved that problem in another way, because I figured that actually I don't need the login_groups table. And yes, I already had the User table in my Database, and my tables had already data too.